# Installing Kali Linux on usb

Tags: usb, kali-linux

Is the "Kali installed USB" a USB that has its own OS? Or is it just another method to install Kali Linux on your computer?

If the latter is correct, than is partitioning my computer's drives necessary in order to keep my current Windows?

Even if i did that, would booting Kali Linux only work on the computer that it was installed?

I'm an amateur who is just starting out. Please help.

Comment: If you're asking those questions, Kali isn't for you.

Comment: Google "Kali Linux revealed".

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, the USB is complete Kali OS to try without installation.
2. 2nd, it is installation media to install Kali Linux.
3. 3rd, you can choose dual boot with windows.
4. No, it will work on any system for install OS or try Kali Linux..

Hope you get it is my first answer...